# Trouble with functions returning bool!

Tags: visual-c++

I don't understand exactly how to use a function that returns a boolean. I know what it is, but I can't figure out how to make it work in my program. I'm trying to say that if my variable "selection" is any letter beween 'A' and 'I' then it is valid and can continue on to the next function which is called `calcExchangeAmt(amtExchanged, selection)`. If it is false I want it to ask the user if they want to repeat the program and if they agree to repeat. I want it to clear the screen and restart to the main function. How do I make my program work as intended?

This is my bool function:

```
bool isSelectionValid(char selection, char yesNo, double amtExchanged)
{
    bool validData;

    validData = true;

    if ((selection >= 'a' && selection <= 'i') || 
        (selection >= 'A' && selection <= 'I'))
    {
        validData = calcExchangeAmt (amtExchanged, selection);
    }
    else(validData == false);
    {
        cout << "Do you wish to continue?  (Y for Yes / N for No)";
        cin >> yesNo;
    }

    do
    {
        main();
    }

    while ((yesNo =='y')||(yesNo == 'Y'));
    {
        system("cls");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get this warning:

> warning C4800: 'double' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code that's generating the error? It should complain about converting 'int', not 'double'. Also, what do you intend by `else(validData == false);`? If you are trying to set the value of validData to true, this won't do it; you are simply comparing `validData` to `true` and doing nothing with the result. There are more problems with this code than I can poke a stick at. Perhaps you should take a step back and describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: in addition to marcelo: provide source code for calcExchangeAmt , the problem is in there, most likely its returns double which you force to bool

Answer (score 1):

A bool function should return true or false. I'm guessing your warning is caused by the fact that you're declaring `validData` as bool, but then assign it a different value (returned by `calcExchangeAmt` function). That value is getting converted from its value type (double) to boolean (true or false).

So, your IsSelectionValid method should just return `true` if selection is valid, or `false` if it's not. Then whatever code needs to know that information can proceed accordingly.

I don't know much C++, so forgive me for syntax problems my code is bound to have, but your code should look something like this:

```
bool isSelectionValid(char selection)
{
  return (selection >= 'a' && selection <= 'i') || (selection >= 'A' && selection <= 'I');
}

void myCallingFunction(double amtExchanged, char selection)
{
   bool isSelectionValid = isSelectionValid(selection);

   if(isSelectionValid)
  {
     double exchangeAmt = calcExchangeAmt (amtExchanged, selection);
  }
  else 
  {
     cout<<"Do you wish to continue?  (Y for Yes / N for No)";
     cin>>yesNo;

     if((yesNo =='y')||(yesNo == 'Y'))
     {
        main(); // or whatever code starts another attempt
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is seriously confusing and very non-C++ like. We normally expect main() to be the function that drives things and calls other functions, not to have it called from some other place. We generally avoid `do` unless there is a compelling reason (and I don't see one here). I think it's highly unlikely that a function called `calcExchangeAmt` returns true or false; I suspect it actually returns a number that you should be doing something else with (showing to the user?).

With all this going on, trying to explain your actual compiler error messages is of limited value. Your code is all inside out and backwards. Anna Lear's answer seems like a better starting point if it makes sense to you.

Comment: Calling `::main()` isn't just unusual, it's forbidden in 3.6.1p3.  (Of course, this could be a class member named `main`, that's allowed)

Answer (score -2):

The type of 0 is not `bool`; true or false is `bool`. It is telling you that 0 is a double, but it is forcing it to a boolean type.

Comment: 0 is false.  `0` is not double, its integer.